# Looking for Free alternative to Google Maps for flutter apps, I want to use a small widget of a Map

Tags: flutter, geolocator

I am looking for an alternative solution to using Google Maps in my flutter app. Google maps is free if you use a URL to open it but you have to pay for the small widget in your app. So I am looking for a FREE alternative small widget of a map that can be in my app. My app uses a geolocator to get the coordinates and I want to use those to live show on the app the location of the user on the map on their device.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map

Comment: mapbox is also a good one that has free tiers